# Keda with prometheus integration

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, keda, keda-scaledjob

Below are the setup details:
keda installed,
prometheus deployed,
through application using below scaled object template for hpa:

```
keda:
  triggers:
    - metadata:
        metricName: container_memory_usage
        query: avg(floor((container_memory_usage_bytes{pod=~"pythonb-.*",container=~"proxy"} / container_spec_memory_limit_bytes != +Inf)  * 100))
        serverAddress: <serveraddress>
        threshold: '70'
      type: prometheus
```

basically we want to scale the deployment based on the given prom query.(based on container memory utilisation of particular pods..if it exceeds 70% then hpa will scale the pods. )
when we try the above query on Prometheus it returns the results as 8.*, 10.*. , 25.3. Basically single element response
But though keda it gives the result as below:

```
kubectl get hpa -n integration keda-pythonb 
NAME                       REFERENCE                    TARGETS                               MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
keda-pythonb   Deployment/pythonb   3500m/70 (avg), 34%/87% + 1 more...   2         10        2          14m
```

Instead of single value it gives 3500m as current value.
does keda convert the data returned from prom query? Any pointers would be helpful.
I hope the prom query is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We just solved this one after a lot of off-and-on hunting. Turns out KEDA has an option called `metricType` that you can specify under `triggers`. TLDR you need to set that to `"Value"`.

To understand why you need to dive into how HPA works in Kubernetes. When you define a `kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler` you specify the metrics that are used for scaling. KEDA does this for you and creates an external metric like this:

```yaml
  metrics:
  - external:
      metric:
        name: ...
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            scaledobject.keda.sh/name: ...
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: ...
    type: External
```

There are `Value` and `AverageValue` metric types. `AverageValue` is the default, meant for metrics like `http-requests-per-second`, which would need to be divided by the number of replicas before compared to the target. `Value`, on the other hand, takes the direct value from your metric without averaging it.

Since your Prometheus query is returning an average across pods already, you need to use `Value`. The clue is in your `kubectl get hpa` output: `3500m/70 (avg)`.

See [docs on HPA with external metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-metrics-not-related-to-kubernetes-objects).

In KEDA that is specified using the `metricType` option under the `triggers` field.

See [KEDA: Scaling Deployments](https://keda.sh/docs/2.9/concepts/scaling-deployments/#triggers)